# Transistor with only 2 pins

Tags: transistors

[image]

The letter "Q" shows that this is a transistor, but it only has 2 pins. Checked with diode mode and resistance mode on multimeter, both shows open circuit. Searched the marking but yielded no results. What kind of transistor is this?

EDIT: The connection looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: A mislabeled capacitor?  What is it connected to?

Comment: @vir One side is connected to a capacitor, the other is connected to cathode pin of an optocoupler.

Comment: That arrangement doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me; could you post some pictures of the area around it on both sides with enough other components to give us an idea of what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @vir i've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the size of R145 the input on J34 is expected to be some high voltage, and that 'Q' implies an active part, the most likely part for this position is a diac.

Comment: I think we have a winner. An image search for diacs shows many that look just like this one. I should have noticed it has no polarity marking.

Comment: @GodJihyo All the diacs I've seen, those looking a lot like this, are labeled DBn, with n being like a 2 or 4 or something single-digit looking. The "C" here is quite annoying. Maybe if more of the body were to be photographed?

Comment: Yes, a DIAC together with the capacitor in this circuit might produce a voltage depending pulse train in the optocoupler, at least it would define a minimum input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

801 usually means 800. The device has no polarity markings. 800pF is not a standard capacitor value, though there were some capacitors made in diode-like packages.

Without more information I would guess it to be an 800V gas discharge or spark gap device that would be used to protect inputs of some kind of telecom or similar gear that has to deal with such things.

From the revised information, I think it could be a current regulator diode which is more-or-less a JFET, so the Q designation makes sense. Possibly 8mA. They're not that common these days. Semtech has some with similar part numbers: https://www.semitec-global.com/uploads/2022/01/P22-23-CRD.pdf. But  upon reflection that's not that likely.

It's also conceivable it's something like a zener to control the turn-on voltage.

In both of the latter cases the diagnosis is contraindicated by the lack of polarity markings so this is still a mystery I think.

There is one more possibility that comes to mind- it could be something more exotic such as an SIDAC or diac that the designer incorporated to give the input some hysteresis. They are bilateral and would be Q-worthy.

Comment: I've added a picture to the question, so maybe you could verify your answer.

Comment: 801 makes me think 800 μA.

Comment: So the "anode" is connected to the cathode pin of optocoupler, and the "cathode" is connected to J4-1. Am i correct?

Comment: If the input is working use a bench supply to slowly increase the input voltage (within ratings) and observe the voltage across the device. If it changes suddenly, decrease the voltage and observe. If it increases smoothly over the range, observe the voltage and current readings.